# Solving used Real Based Methods: $\int_0^x \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + a\right)^m}\:dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, beta-function

In working on integrals for the past couple of months, I've come across different cases of the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I\left(x,a,k,n,m\right) = \int_0^x \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + a\right)^m}\:dt
\end{equation}

Where $x,a\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Here the method that I've taken is rather simple and I was curious as to other 'Real' Based methods could be employed with this integral? I also believe that with the conditions I've set on the parameters that it is convergent. If I'm able to expand those conditions, could you please advise.

Interested in special cases too!

The method I took:

First I wanted to bring the 'a' out the front:

\begin{equation}
I(x,a,k,n,m) =  \int_0^x \frac{t^k}{\left(a\left[\left(a^{-\frac{1}{n}}t\right)^n + 1\right]\right)^m}\:dt = \frac{1}{a^m} \int_0^x \frac{t^k}{\left(\left(a^{-\frac{1}{n}}t\right)^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt
\end{equation}
Here let $u = a^{-\frac{1}{n}}t$ Thus,

\begin{equation}
 I(x,a,k,n,m) = \frac{1}{a^m} \int_0^{a^{-\frac{1}{n}}x} \frac{\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}u\right)^k}{\left(u^n + 1\right)^m}a^{\frac{1}{n}}\:du = a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m}\int_0^{a^{-\frac{1}{n}}x} \frac{u^k}{\left(u^n + 1\right)^m}\:du = a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m}I(a^{-\frac{1}{n}}x,1,k,n,m)
\end{equation}

From here I will use $I$ in place of $I(x,a,k,n,m)$ for ease of typing. The next step is to make the substitution $w = u^n$ to yield:

\begin{equation}
 I = a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m}\int_0^{ax^n} \frac{w^\frac{k}{n}}{\left(w + 1\right)^m}\frac{\:dw}{nw^{\frac{n - 1}{n}}} = \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m}\int_0^{ax^n} \frac{w^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}}{\left(w + 1\right)^m}\:dw
\end{equation}

Here make the substitution $z = \frac{1}{1 + w}$ to yield:

\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m}\int_1^{\frac{1}{1 + ax^n}} z^m \left(\frac{1 - z}{z}\right)^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}\right) \:dz = \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m}\int_{\frac{1}{1 + ax^n}}^1 z^{m - \frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}\left(1 - z\right)^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}\:dz \\
&= \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m} \left[\int_0^1 z^{m - \frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}\left(1 - z\right)^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}\:dz - \int_0^{\frac{1}{1 + ax^n}} z^{m - \frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}\left(1 - z\right)^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - 1}\:dz \ \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m} \left[B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) -  B\left( \frac{1}{1 + ax^n}; m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}  \right)\right]
\end{align}

Where $B(a,b)$ is the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and $B(x; a,b)$ is the [Incomplete Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

And so, we arrive at:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^x \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + a\right)^m}\:dt = \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m} \left[B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) -  B\left(\frac{1}{1 + ax^n}; m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}  \right)\right]
\end{equation}

Here we observe that for convergence:

\begin{equation}
 m - \frac{k + 1}{n} \gt 0,\quad  \frac{k + 1}{n} \gt 0,\quad n \neq 0
\end{equation}

Note: when $x \rightarrow \infty$ we have:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + a\right)^m}\:dt = \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m} B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) 
\end{equation}

---

Update: Today I realised that we can use this result for another integral:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt
\end{equation}

This is achieved through a simple use of Feynman's Trick. Here we  consider the case when $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $a = 1$. We see that

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dk}\left[ \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt \right]&= \frac{d}{dk}\left[\frac{1}{n}B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right)\right] \\
 \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt &= \frac{1}{n^2}B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{k + 1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) \right]
\end{align}

Thus, 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt = \lim_{k \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{n^2}B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{k + 1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) \right]
\end{equation}

And finally:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^m}\:dt = \frac{1}{n^2}B\left(m - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(m - \frac{1}{n}\right) \right]
\end{equation}

Note: In the case where $m = 1$ we arrive:

\begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln(t)}{\left(t^n + 1\right)^1}\:dt &= \frac{1}{n^2}B\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \cdot -\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}\cdot -\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\end{align}

Thus:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln(t)}{t^n + 1}\:dt = -\frac{\pi^2}{n^2} \operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{n} \right)\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: damn bro that's a crazy integral

Comment: It's more that I see it so often I wanted to finally get it out in a closed form so I could be done with solving it 10 different ways haha. Please if you have time look in detail. I do believe it's correct, but I need some wise eyes to have a look over.

Comment: Would this work for $n=2$, $a=\frac{1+b}{1-b}$ for some $|b|<1$, and some integer $m\geq1$, and $k=2K$ for integer $0\leq K\leq m-1$? I need to know for $$F(m;b)=\int_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+b\cos x)^m}$$

Comment: @clathratus - Given that the integrand is discontinuous at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ - do you expect there to be an elementary primitive?. Regardless, if you changed the upper bound to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then the half-tangent substitution should yield an elementary form.

Comment: Well after Tangent Half angle sub, $$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(1+b\cos x)^n}=2\int_0^\infty \frac{(t^2+1)^{n-1}}{((1-b)t^2+1+b)^{n}}dt$$ Then using The binomial theorem, $$F(n;b)=\frac2{(1-b)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{2k}}{\left[t^2+\frac{1+b}{1-b}\right]^n}dt$$

Comment: That final integral can be solved with your method

Comment: Check out this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3077345/583016  It's also on our document. I have made a desmos page and it seems as if it works.

Comment: @clathratus - Wii do.

Answer (score 2):

NOT A SOLUTION:

I've found some special cases on this site that I will list (this will evolve as I find more special (but generalised) cases:

1. [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Evaluate the integral $ \int _0^{+\infty} \frac{x^m}{(a+bx^n)^p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319438/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracxmabxnp?rq=1)