# Would you like to know the formula for the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+1\right)^{n}} d x$ where $n\in N$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions, trigonometric-integrals

When struggling with the integral in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4365540/732917) ,
$$
\int \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+1\right)^{2}} d x= \frac{\pi}{8 \sqrt{2}},
$$
I encountered the simpler integral, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{4}+1} d x=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Then I am wondering how hard the integral will be as the power of $x^4+1$ increases, differentiation come to my mind and reminded me that it is easier than integration.  So I started my journey by defining $$
I_{n}(a):=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+a\right)^{n}} d x, \text { where } n \in \mathbb{N} \textrm{ and }a>0.
$$

and then begin with $I_1(a)$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{4}+a} d x &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}+\frac{a}{x^{2}}} d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x^{2}})+(1+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x^{2}})}{x^{2}+\frac{a}{x^{2}}} d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}\right)^{2}-2 \sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}\right)^{2}+2 \sqrt{a}} \\
& =\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2} a^{\frac{1}{4}}}\left[\ln \left| \frac{x+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}-\sqrt{2 \sqrt{a}}}{x+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}+\sqrt{2 \sqrt{a}}}\right|\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} a^{\frac{1}{4}}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}}{\sqrt{2 \sqrt{a}}}\right)\right]_0^{\infty}
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence $$
I_{1}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{4}+a} d x=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2} a^{\frac{1}{4}}}
$$
Differentiating $I_1(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ by $(n-1)$ times yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d^{n-1}}{d a^{n-1}}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{x^{4}+a}\right) d x&=\frac{d}{d a^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}} a^{-\frac{1}{4}}\right) \\
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1) ! x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+a\right)^{n}} d x&=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(-\frac{5}{4}\right) \cdots\left(-\frac{4 n-3}{4}\right) a^{-\frac{4 n-3}{4}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Simplifying and expressing in product gives
$$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+a\right)^{n}} d x= 
\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4^{n}(n-1) ! a^{\frac{4 n-3}{4}}} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(4 k-3)}
$$

In particular, when $a=1$,
$$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+1\right)^{n}} d x= 
\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4^{n}(n-1) !} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(4 k-3)}
$$

By the formula, we can easily find, for example,

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+a\right)^{2}} d x= \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4^{2}\cdot 1!} \cdot 1 =\frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{16},
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+a\right)^{3}} d x= \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4^{3} \cdot 2 !} \cdot 1 \cdot 5 =\frac{5 \pi \sqrt{2}}{128}, 
$$$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+1\right)^{4}} d x=\frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4^{4} \cdot 3 !} \cdot 5 \cdot 9=\frac{15 \sqrt{2} \pi}{512},
$$

$\vdots \tag*{} $

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+1\right)^{10}} d x =\frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4^{10} \cdot 9 !} \cdot 1 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 21 \cdot 25 \cdot 29 \cdot 33=\frac{1762475 \sqrt{2} \pi}{134217728}
\end{aligned}
$$
*Checked by the [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%E2%88%9A2%2A%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B%5Cleft%28x%5E%7B4%7D%2B1%5Cright%29%5E%7B10%7D%7D%20d%20x).

Although I had found the formula for the integral, the last product $ \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(4 k-3)$ can’t be easily found. Do we have ***any method*** to simplify the product?

For generalization, I believe that if we can handle the first one, say

$$
I_1(a)=\int_{c}^{d} \frac{f(x)}{x^{m}+a} d x,
$$
we can discover, by differentiation, the formula for $$I_n(a)=\int_{c}^{d} \frac{f(x)}{(x^{m}+a)^n} d x.$$

Do you ***agree***? ***Comments*** and ***alternate*** solutions are warmly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well I need to think about the product but I found another way (It's not elementary as yours).
Considering,
$$I_{n}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^4+a)^{n}}dx$$
Substituting $x=ua^{0.25}$ leads to,
$$a^{3/4-n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^2}{(u^4+1)^{n}}du$$
Again letting $k=u^4+1$ gives,
$$\frac{1}{4}a^{3/4-n}\int_{1}^{\infty}(k-1)^{-0.25}k^{-n} dk$$
Letting, $k=\frac{1}{\phi}$ gives us the beta function as one's expecting,
$$\frac{1}{4}a^{3/4-n}B(3/4,n-3/4)$$
Using the definition of beta function that,
$$\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
We can simply evaluate and moreover we can see 3/4 cancelling out.

Comment: Basically the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, derive the reduction formula
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{(1+x^{4})^{n}} d x
= I_n= \frac{4n-7}{4(n-1)}I_{n-1}
$$
along with the starting value $I_1=\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}$