# On $F(n;a)=\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+a\cos x)^n}$

Tags: integration

I am currently working on, out of interest, the integral 
$$F(n;a)=\int_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+a\cos x)^n}$$
For $a\in(-1,1)$ and $n\in \Bbb N$. I would like to know if my methods are correct or if there are any other ways to go about this.

Attempt:

Starting with $t=\tan\frac{x}2$,
$$F(n;a)=2\int_0^\infty \frac1{\left[1+a\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right]^n}\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}$$
$$F(n;a)=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\left(t^2+1\right)^{n-1}}{\left[(1-a)t^2+1+a\right]^n}\mathrm dt$$
Then using the binomial theorem,
$$F(n;a)=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{\left[(1-a)x^2+1+a\right]^n}\mathrm dx$$
$$F(n;a)=\frac2{(1-a)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{\left[x^2+\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right]^n}\mathrm dx$$
We then recall the work of my collaborator [@DavidG](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/150203/davidg), 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{q}}{\left[x^w+b\right]^p}\mathrm dx=\frac{b^{\frac{1+q}{w}-p}}{w}\frac{\Gamma\left(p-\frac{1+q}{w}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+q}{w}\right)}{\Gamma\left(p\right)}$$
So with $w=2$, $b=\frac{1+a}{1-a}$, $p=n$, and $q=2k$,
$$F(n;a)=\frac1{(1-a)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^{\frac{2k+1}{2}-n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}$$
$$F(n;a)=\frac1{(1-a)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^{\frac{2k+1}{2}-n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)}{k!\Gamma(n-k)}$$
Which *is* a closed form. Did I do this correctly? How else could've this been done? Thanks.

Comment: Take $$I(b)=\int_0^{\pi} \frac {dx}{b+a\cos x}=\frac {\pi}{\sqrt {b^2-a^2}}$$ Now differentiate w.r.t "$b$" , $n-1$ times and then substitute $b=1$ to reach near the answer.

Comment: Looks spot on to me. You could use the following to simplify the sum slightly:

$
\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^{\frac{2k+1}{2}-n} = \left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^k \cdot \left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^{\frac{1}{2} - n} 
$

Comment: It probably wouldn't assist with the integral, but you could use: $\left(\frac{1 + a}{1 - a}\right)^k = \left( 1 + \frac{2a}{1 - a}\right)^k$ and then expand with the binomial theorem. It _MAY_ lead to something useful,