# Jump discontinuity in antiderivative

Tags: integration, periodic-functions, continuity

I am dealing with integral

$I=\int_0^{\pi}dx\frac{\sin^2x}{a^2+\sin^2x}.$

I know the answer is

$I=\pi(1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}).$

However I am having some uncertainty getting there. I know that before plugging in the integration limits the solution looks like

$I= \left[x-\frac{a \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a} \tan x\right)}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right]^{x=\pi}_{x=0}$

but at first sight this would yield merely $\pi$. I can see that the right step to recover the correct solution is to take

$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a} \tan x\right)\Big\rvert_{x=\pi}=\pi$

however how do I justify this (besides that it yields the correct answer)?

Comment: You cannot integrate something containing $\tan x$ from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$.

Comment: Split it up from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ and $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

First notice that the integral exists for all $a\in\Bbb R$, and from symmetry 
$$I(a)=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2x}{a^2+\sin^2x}dx\\
=\pi-2a^2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{a^2+\sin^2x}$$
Then we have that $\sin^2x=\frac12(1-\cos2x)$ so 
$$I(a)=\pi-4a^2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{2a^2+1-\cos2x}\\
=\pi+2a^2\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{\cos x-2a^2-1}$$
Then from [the comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3077345/583016), we have that 
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{b+a\cos x}=\frac\pi{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}$$
(I can show you a proof if you'd like). So of course 
$$I(a)=\pi+\frac{2a^2\pi}{\sqrt{(2a^2+1)^2-1}}=\pi+\frac{a\pi}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$
And from the definition of $I(a)$, we have that $I(a)=I(-a)$ so your desired result:
$$\frac1\pi I(a)=1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$