# Closed form Integral of $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + a x^b}$

Tags: integration

Is there a closed form for the following integral (with $a$ and $b$ are given constants)?

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + a x^b}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.Stackexchange! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sadly, i don't even know where to start. I did try Mathematica though, but didn't get an answer for the general a and b values.

Comment: @TrungPhan - are there any constraints on $b$?

Comment: If you reposition the integral into the form:

$$\frac{1}{a} \int_0^x \frac{t^{-2}}{\frac{1}{a} + t^{b - 2}} \:dt $$

And then you can form an Incomplete Beta Representation which I discuss in detail here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d

Comment: @DavidG. This was a real good post !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - it comes into handy A LOT! :-)