# List of Integration Formulas

Tags: calculus, integration, big-list

While going through some of my notes, I came across a formula for evaluating an integral of the form: $$\int_0^\infty {\frac{dx}{x^n+1}} = \frac{\pi}{n\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$

I was wondering if any other formulas exist for solving more complicated integrals where an antiderivative can't easily be found. If you could also include a proof of said formula, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The proof of this formula is very easy with complex integration (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247866) and very tedious with real integration.

Comment: @JeanMarie - With a single complex change of variable, or two simple change of variables this can be achieved very EASILY with real based methods.

Comment: @DavidG I am interested by a reference to this method.

Comment: @JeanMarie - I cover a more complicated form here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d

Comment: @DavidG Thank you very much !

Comment: @JeanMarie - No worries, I hope it's of use :-)